# Journey Builder with updated data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have an onboarding journey that helps clients activate their new SaaS product.

We send them a series of 5 emails with next steps and accelerate them through the journey if they do more than 1 of the 4 things they must do to activate their service.  Currently, I have a data extension that's built from a query that looks at multiple tables within the SalesCloud sync.  Then I use decision splits to see if certain fields have a certain status.

My question is:
Once a contact has entered a journey, are the fields within a data extension static?   Or will those fields be updated as I have an automation that runs every hour to update those fields when action is taken.

Comment: Is this the answer to my question? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5   
`To evaluate all records in a data extension each time according to the entry source's schedule, select Evaluate all records. Use this option only when records in the data extension were updated. Using this option typically results in slower processing.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a contact has entered the journey, all the data in your entry source DE for that contact will be saved in journey data.

If you look at any decision split, you will see two options

- Journey Data 
  : Point in Time data when the contact enters the journey (it never changes)
   Lives in system memory, so it
  is faster to access than Contact Data
- Contact Data: A system of Record - always has the most up-to-date
  value

You can always update the records and fields in the entry source DE, but to get the most up-to-date value, you need to link the entry source DE to the contact record under an attribute group in contact builder, Data Designer.

Steps to do this.

1. Go to Contact builder -> Data designer
2. Create an attribute group
3. Link your Entry Source DE to Contact record by creating one to one mapping between the Contact Key on the left side to the Subscriber Key in your DE on the right side.
4. Give 10 to 15 minutes, so that this mapping will reflect in the
   decision split in journey builder
5. Now, go to your journey, click on decision split, select contact data, select the attribute group you have created, select the entry source DE, select the relevant field to make your decision. This field will now give you the latest value which is updated by your automation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any workaround to creating attribute groups for this type of journey (that is monitoring changes within entry source data extension data?  It appears that I'll end up with MANY attribute groups, if I do this.   If the data in the data extension is being updated by a query, can I use a FIRE event to force journey builder data to 'look at' the new data vs the static data upon entry?

Comment: If we use fire event to force Journey to fire again, then it will be treated as another customer entry to the journey. I don't think you want that.  We can use one attribute group to link all the DEs that you want to refer to in the journey.

Comment: That's helpful.  I think the best solution is to create a 'Campaign' attribute group and nest campaigns like this within.